# MariaDB / MySQL: Where ANY of set IN other set - Possible?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am in need of help:

I have a table, containing a field "usergroups" which is a varchar and I have a set like ('group1', 'group3').

Now I need to filter rows from my table - let's call it "tbl" - where one of the actual "usergroups" is IN the said set.

So my current approach is simple:
`` ... WHERE `usergroup` IN ('group1', 'group3') ``

But now I need to change the data model, so that "usergroup" can have multiple values. The idea is to set it to a comma seperated list like "group1,group2" - But this is not fixed.

What is the best way to achieve multiple groups on the "left" (row) side?
The end result should be that I can filter for all rows, where at least one usergroup is in the set of groups ('group1', 'group3').

Important to know: There is no table containing the "right" set of groups. This comes from the application's filters.

Just a pseudo code idea to descrbe my goals better:
`` ... WHERE ONE OF SPLIT(`usergroups`, ',') IN ('group1', 'group2') ``

Performance note:
The table contains about 30.000 rows and grows by about 5.000 rows per year. The SQL statements filtering for those groups are called about once per second average spread over all users of the system. There are lots fo other filters before the actual group matching so the result set should be already brought down to a few hundred max

Comment: *But now I need to change the data model, so that "usergroup" can have multiple values. The idea is to set it to a comma seperated list like "group1,group2"* Wrong idea. You need in classic M:N relation which needs in intermediate junction table.

Comment: @akina thanks for the suggestion. I know this is the "clean" way but I will likely not be able to chnage this "idea".

Comment: If so then think about converting the values to JSON arrays with string functions and testing with JSON_OVERLAPS().

Comment: With the correct indexing there shouldn't be performance troubles with an intermediate table. I recommending setting it up, testing it, and showing its a "performing idea".

Comment: Please show us suggested SQL and relevant data.  Prose is too imprecise.

Comment: Also [FIND_IN_SET](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/find_in_set/), but don't expect any index performance with it.